# Best way to do a query with a large number of possible joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

On the project I'm working on we have an activity table and each activity can be linked to one of about 20 different "activity details" tables...

e.g. If the activity was of type "work", then it would have a corresponding activity_details_*work* record, if it was of type "sick leave" then it would have a corresponding activity_details_*sickleave* record and so on.

Currently we are loading the activities and then for each activity we have a separate query to go fetch the activity details from the relevant table. This obviously doesn't scale well if you have thousands of activities.

So my initial thought was to have a single query which fetches the activities and joins the details in one go e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM activity
LEFT JOIN activity_details_1_work ON ...
LEFT JOIN activity_details_2_sickleave ON ...
LEFT JOIN activity_details_3_travelwork ON ...
...etc...
LEFT JOIN activity_details_20_yearleave ON ...
```

But this will result in each record having 100's of fields, most of which are empty and that feels nasty.

Lazy-loading the details isn't really an option either as the details are almost always requested in the core logic, at least for the main types anyway.

Is there a super clever way of doing this that I'm not thinking of?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to query on attributes of any of the joined tables? What is your RDBMS and the "hosting" environment? (there are RDBMS-specific solutions to this).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Nope I don't need to query on the details, it's informational stuff mostly. We are using MySQL and connecting to it with mysqli, then just using a simple bit of code to map the data records to the relevant classes e.g. Activity, ActivityDetailsAbsence etc

Comment: Depending on the size of the tables, this query is gonna be really heavy. Generating an activity feed is something that NoSQL does very well. Might want to see how redis/mongo might be suited for this use case?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to define a view for each ActivityType, that is tailored specifically to that activity.

Then add an index on the Activity table lead by the ActivityType field. Cluster said index unless there is an overwhelming need for some other to be clustered (or performance benchmarking shows some other clustering selection to be more performant).

Is there a particular reason why this degree of denormalization was designed in? Is that reason well known?

Comment: I'm not sure the exact reason it was done like this but the details tables do have a large number of fields on them, for instance the activity_details_work table has 20+ informational fields, do you think it would have been better if all the details were originally stored in the activity table then?

Comment: @MeatPopsicle: It's not that 20+ fields is _a priori_ a lot of fields, but that so little meta knowledge about the data is captured. But only a fool rushes in to change before understanding the original motivations.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are your activity tables are like `(date_from, date_to, with_who, descr)` or something to that effect. As Pieter suggested, consider tossing in a type varchar or enum field in there, so as to deal with a single details table.

If there are rational reasons to keep the tables apart, consider adding triggers that maintain boolean/tinyint fields (`has_work`, `has_sickleave`, etc), or a bit string (`has_activites_of_type` where the first position amounts to `has_work`, the next to `has_sickleave`, etc.).

Either way, you'll probably be better off by fetching the activity's details in one or more separate queries -- if only to avoid field name collisions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think enum is the way to go, because as you say there might be 1000's of activities, then altering your `activity` table would become an issue.

There is no point doing a left join on a large number of tables either.

So the options that you have are :

1. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898628/mysql-join-a-table-which-its-name-is-stored-as-a-field-value-on-another-table) The first comment might be useful.
2. I am guessing that your activity table has a field called `activity_type_id`.
   Build a table called `activity_types` containing fields `activity_type_id`, `activity_name`, `activity_details_table_name`. First query in the following way

   activity
   inner join
   activity_types
   using( activity_type_id )

This query gives you the table name on which to query for the details.
This way you can add any new activity type just by adding a row in the activity_types table.